# Session.StatusCallback cannot be resolved to a type - Facebook API

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

I followed the login authentication tutorial on Facebook and have copied the following code into my android application

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
    new Session.StatusCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, 
            SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
```

However, it is giving me the following errors:

```
Session.StatusCallback cannot be resolved to a type
```

Which is leading to the following errors:

```
callback cannot be resolved to a variable
```

There's also other places where Facebook API calls are made that are giving me errors, but it's not in all the Facebook API calls. Another place I'm getting an error is the following:

```
Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, 
                    new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // If the response is successful
                    if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            // Set the id for the ProfilePictureView
                            // view that in turn displays the profile picture.
                            Log.d("MainActivity", "onComplete() User logged in");
                            parent.owner = MainKickback.userConnection.add(new User(user.getId()));

                            EventFragment e = (EventFragment) fragments[UPCOMING_EVENTS];
                            e.populateEvents();
                        }
                    }
                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                        // Handle errors, will do so later.
                    }
                }
            });
            request.executeAsync();
```

where it does not recognize Request.GraphUserCallback, and then executeAsync(). I get the following errors:

```
Request.GraphUserCallback cannot be resolved to a type
The method executeAsync() is undefined for the type DownloadManager.Request
```

Does anyone have any advice as to how to fix this?

Thank you for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem as your first one, and I solved it by removing

```
import android.service.textservice.SpellCheckerService.Session;
```

and adding

```
import com.facebook.Session;
```

Comment: You are a life saver!! Why do you think the SpellCheckerService.Session was creating a problem, because I had the exact same issue and it got solved by removing the statement!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, and the problem was that I had these two imports in the file

```
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.service.textservice.SpellCheckerService.Session;
```

And those Request and Session modules were overriding

```
com.facebook.Session
com.facebook.Request
```

I actually just removed the two android imports and everything worked nicely.  They didn't seem to be used, but eclipse added them in for some strange reason.

Judging by your output

```
The method executeAsync() is undefined for the type DownloadManager.Request
```

I'd say it sounds like you have the same imports happening somewhere and they're overriding the facebook imports.

Answer (score 2):

Got this issue when having both Request and Session classes from Volley framework already imported. Try using the class with the package name for Session and Request, it worked for me. See below's code.

```
private com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback callback = 
    new com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void call(com.facebook.Session session, 
            SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, which import do you use ? I use this for the Callback:

```
import com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback;
```

Which Facebook SDK are you using ? The newest one ?
I am  using latest sdk 4.01 butin this sdk is not support this pakage

Comment: I am using import com.facebook.SessionState; and importing anything else gives me a conflict. And I am using Facebook SDK 3.0.1 i think

Comment: Hmmm silly question but, did you imported the facebook sdk as an android project and included that into your buildpath of your project as a library project ?

Comment: Yes, I did. This entire project was working before, then I updated my git repo and things broke and now I'm trying to fix it again. Other calls to Facebook API are not throwing errors. But these particular ones are and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I had a message: "Cannot resolve symbol Session". So, the problem was in non-plugged library "facebook". I resolved it so.
    1. Open Project Structure (File > Project Structure).
    2. Select Modules on the left pane.
    3. Choose your project name.
    4. Click Dependencies tab.
    5. Click on the plus sign in the bottom. Select "Module dependency" and click "facebook".
    6. Press OK, then OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.vishal.example;

import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.Request;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private View otherView;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Set View that should be visible after log-in invisible initially
        otherView = (View) findViewById(R.id.other_views);
        otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // To maintain FB Login session
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   // Called when session changes
   private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback()
   {
       @Override
       public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
       {
           onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
       }
   };

   // When session is changed, this method is called from callback method
    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
    {
         final TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
         final TextView gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender);
         final TextView location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
         // When Session is successfully opened (User logged-in)
         if (state.isOpened())
         {
             Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
             // make request to the /me API to get Graph user
             Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
             {
                 // callback after Graph API response with user
                 @Override
                 public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                 {
                     if (user != null)
                     {
                         // Set view visibility to true
                        otherView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        // Set User name 
                        name.setText("Hello " + user.getName());
                        // Set Gender
                        gender.setText("Your Gender: " + user.getProperty("gender").toString());
                        location.setText("Your Current Location: " + user.getLocation().getProperty("name").toString());
                     }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
         }
         else if(state.isClosed())
         {
             Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
             otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.i(TAG, "OnActivityResult...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Reference link for facebook sdk where You can download and use it. its work for me
http://www.filedropper.com/facebooksdk

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the FB SDK and re-download it.
Your SDK is probably corrupted by others who pushed to git.