# Request.GraphUserCallback cannot be resolved to a type in ParseLoginUI

Tags: java, android, facebook, parse-platform

I am trying to use ParseLoginUI but there are several errors, one of which is the following

> Request.GraphUserCallback cannot be resolved to a type

I have tried to import `com.facebook.session;` and I have seen the other solutions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093932/request-graphusercallback-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926123/session-statuscallback-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-facebook-api), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661847/request-graphusercallback-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-connectplugin-java)) but they are not working. This issue is happening in the `ParseLoginFragment` file. I have the following imports:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.parse.LogInCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils;
import com.parse.ParseTwitterUtils;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;
import com.parse.twitter.Twitter;
```

I have added the FacebookSDK project in my workspace and have added it to my buildpath for `ParseLoginUI`. If anyone knows the solution, the help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is still relevant, because it has been long time since you asked, but if you or anyone reads this maybe I can help/

I had the same problem, and then I tried the folowing:
I deleted this import:

```
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
```

and added this imports:

```
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.Request;
```

after doing so, I got an error in **Request.GraphUserCallback()**
I don't know why it does this, but hover over the problem and it will let you **implement the unimplemented method **

```
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
```

*(the method exist but for some reason it doesn't recognize it)*, 
just copy everything that is inside the  original **onompleted** and it suppose to work!

Hopes this helps